# Remove delay time: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep using c# (Code Included)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a winform app, which shows some information in time, every time it loads the data, I set a delay time of 7 sec like this: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000) so the info can be viewed. I want to have a buttom that allows me to jump to the next information without waiting.

The logic I use is as follows: get Information, if any, wait 7 sec, next data, and so on. So if I press the button I'd like to set that time to 0.

Is there any way to cancel the waiting period?

here is the code:

```
ManualResetEvent wait_handle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

{...}

```
private void TheLoop(object stateinfo)
    {
        bool hasInfo = true;            
        bool hasLines = GetLinesOnProduction();
        while (doLoop)
        {
            wait_handle.WaitOne();

            if (hasLines)
            {
                param1 = Lines[CurrentLine].line;
                param2 = Lines[CurrentLine].WO;

                //Here I query the DB for the CurrentLine Data                    
                ShowLineInformation(CurrentLine);
                ShowChartByHour(param1, param2, out hasInfo);
                if (hasInfo)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);                                        
                //Here I move to the next line
                if (CurrentLine < Lines.Count - 1)
                    CurrentLine++;
                else
                {

                    CurrentLine = 0;  //Start all over again
                    hasLines = GetLinesOnProduction();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40000);  //(No Lines)Wait to query for lines again
                hasLines = GetLinesOnProduction();
            }
        }
    }

private void btnPauseResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnPauseResume.Text == "Pause")
        {
            btnPauseResume.Text = "Resume";
            wait_handle.Reset();
        }
        else
        {
            btnPauseResume.Text = "Pause";
            wait_handle.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your code.  You should probably use multiple buttons.

Comment: `wait_handle.WaitOne();` only waits until the wait_handle is Set(). You have to specify the amount of milliseconds to wait, in this case `WaitOne(7000)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster but I use that WaitOne(); for Pause/Resume the thread, I don't want any waiting time at that point. As far as I know, I have to place it where I want to do those operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing Thread.Sleep, you can use a wait event, and simply set it to cancel the wait. Something like this:

```
var waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
bool wasCanceled = waiter.WaitOne(7000);
if(wasCanceled)
    // Jump to next...


// Cancel the wait from another thread
waiter.Set()
```

Comment: thanks, the thing is that I also have a Pause/Resume buttom, and that will affect its functionality.

Comment: Hey, I combined the Pause/Resume with your solution, and both work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `Thread.Sleep`, which will suspend all activity in your UI, use a *timer* instead.  With a timer, the UI can still response to events while your timer *callback* is pending, and when you click the button, you can cancel the timer.

Comment: Thanks for respond, I also use one buttom to Pause/Resume the thread like @CodeCaster said, will be that a problem with your solution?

Comment: If you need to pause and resume, you would have to write your own code to support that.  `Timer` doesn't have that ability built in.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up the delay by `lock`ing an `object` and then executing a [Monitor.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdc87f8y.aspx) on with a delay of 7 seconds.  Then, from the form, when the button is pushed, `lock` the `object` and do a [Monitor.PulseAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulseall.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ManualResetHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
// Declare it as class member
ManualResetHandle _manualResetHandle = new ManualResetHandle();

// Wait in your process for seven seconds, or until it is Set()
_manualResetHandle.WaitOne(7000);

// Set() it in your click event handler:
_manualResetHandle.Set();
```

Comment: thanks for respond, I use that for pause/resume the thread, I don't think that's gonna work to remove the waiting time.

Comment: Nothing. The logic I use is as follows: get Information, if any, wait 7 sec, next data, and so on. So if I press the button I'd like to set that time to 0.

Comment: @Somebody that's exactly what should happen when you use the code above. I have to agree with SLaks here, please show some code you've already got.